# Porque a folha de estilos não está sendo carregada?

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável

Estou tentando usar `urls amigáveis` mas estou tendo alguns problemas no processo de aprendizado. O problema agora é que a página não me devolve os estilos da página.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tratamentos/(.*) index.php?tratamentos=$1
```

Estou enviando esta url:

```
http://dent.axitech.com.br/tratamentos/aparelhos-dentarios
```

**Pergunta:** Porque a index não me devolve os estilos?

Comment: Como está a chamada dos links dos estilos no html?

Comment: Considerando que a index.php entenda que está na raiz do site, dessa forma .... **<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/slick/slick.css?v=ABABqGOv" />**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que o problema seja porque você está usando o RewriteBase no seu htaccess. E como as URL's relativas são sempre calculadas seguindo a URL base, provavelmente sempre que você entra em uma página a base vira esta própria página, quebrando os links relativos do CSS.

Existem alguns tópicos no stackoverflow em inglês de pessoas que passaram pelo mesmo problema, vou deixá-los aqui:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899991/htaccess-rewrite-breaks-relative-paths
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess

Considere adicionar a tag `<BASE>` no head da sua página, apontando para a raiz, sempre.

Comment: Pode me explicar em curto a necessidade da `<BASE>` ... eu a desconhecia. Já adicionei a página :)

Comment: O tag base define um caminho base para cada página. Imagina que você, quando abre qualquer um dos arquivos do site, ele vai olhar primeiramente o htacess para procurar a base da URL, neste caso você esta reescrevendo a mesma. A tag sobrescreve o que você modificou